# The Great Escape: Room 1

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, knowledge

You wake up trapped in a room.
In front of you is a door. Next to the door there is a computer.

On the computer you see the following

> Select the correct image to open the door
>
> Tries Left: 1

[image: Screen Images]

Underneath the image you see the following

> The key to the door is given in verse
>
> Lineup the objects after they're cursed
>
> Count to 10 for each pair, before they can take you anywhere
>
> Dot 1 and 11 and you won't go wrong
>
> Separate after 8, and negate the long
>
> At last you're here, where all's been said, the final clue is above your head

This is my first puzzle, I hope you have fun, and I'd very much like feedback.

Hint 1: easier clue 1

> To find the key, the first thing to do,
>  is concatenate the cursed hue

Hint 2: Clue for line 4

> A disarrayed approach will get you nowhere
> Think like a programmer, we like to start with nothing

Easier version of Hint 2:
Hint 2: Clue for line 4

> A disarrayed approach will get you nowhere (so use the opposite of a "disarrayed" approach
> Think like a programmer, we like to start with 0

Hint 3: Clue for line 6

> The order is important

Hint 4: Clue for line 5

> Use the same logic as line 4, the second half is a clue for how the numbers are used

Hint 5: Once you know what to do with the image

> use https://www.colorcodepicker.com/?pn=2O4fA.png to get the hex codes, I realized that different color pickers get slightly different results

Hint 6:

> Once you reached the last line, there is one more connection you have to make, the thing being above your head is the final clue, not the answer

Edit: I had to make a correction. Minor spoiler for step 1

> I realized when I was going through the answers, that some of my numbers were wrong, I've updated the image

Comment: This is a great first puzzle! Take a tour here https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour  to earn a badge! Hope you stay here on Puzzling SE!

Answer (score 17):

Is this the answer..Thanks to the answer by SKOG.

> **Bucket** (Water-Carrier another name for Aquarius Constellation in Latin)

The key to the door is given in verse
Lineup the objects after they're cursed

> Convert the colour of the images to hexadecimal value.(Hex is one kind of cursing)

Count to 10 for each pair, before they can take you anywhere

> Take pairs of 2 and convert to decimal format. You get 45030718117289879.

Dot 1 and 11 and you won't go wrong

> replace 1 and 11 with .(dot)

Separate after 8, and negate the long

> Separate after the number 8 between 1 and 11.(To identify which 8). Negate after the 8

At last you're here, where all's been said, the final clue is above your head.

> The number is coordinates for a constellation. Format: HH MM SS.S -±DD MM SS.SSS. Convert number to valid format(For example: 45 is 21 in HH. Do this for all Hours, minutes, seconds and then degrees, minutes, seconds). You get **21 03 07.8 -01 13 29.879** as the final coordinates.
>  The constellation at this co-ordinate is Aquarius which in Latin means Water Carrier.. Hinting that the answer is bucket. Coordinate to constellation converter used: http://djm.cc/constellation.html

Comment: I realized going through your answer that the final info I had was wrong. 
I had to update the image, I'm sorry for the mistake. 
On line 3 you made a slight mistake (don't change a string format) 
There is a better interpretation of line 4 
If you redo step one now you'll get slightly different numbers, which will make it more clear when they are used correctly
Your answer is great, but there are better interpretations (IMHO) of the lines that lead to the correct answer

Comment: Also your use of the numbers, reverses the order of the last line, it was written that way for a reason. If that makes any sense

Answer (score 10):

I think I have most of it, but I'm having trouble with the final line.

**Lineup the objects after they're cursed**

> Hex color values (cursed=hexed) are 2d001e 475111 1c624f, then concatenate for 2d001e4751111c624f

**Count to 10 for each pair, before they can take you anywhere**

> Convert every two numbers to decimal (count to 10), for 45030718117289879.

**Dot 1 and 11 and you won't go wrong**

> Dot the 1 and 11: 4503071.811.7289879

**Separate after 8, and negate the long**

> Separate at 8, turn the longer string negative: 4503071.8 -11.7289879

**At last you're here, where all's been said, the final clue is above your head**

> I believe this is coordinates of a star in a constellation. I may have done something wrong, but I don't know what system is needed here.

Comment: I think your reasoning should be correct, but I don't think that number can fit in a celestial coordinate system, the first number seems way too big.

Comment: It's been pointed out to me by someone else that "1 and 11" can also mean the first and 11th digits, and that after the 8 could be the eighth digit. This might give 4.5003071, -811.7289879. Second number still seems a bit large.

Comment: Might it mean to replace 1 and 11 with dot.

Comment: I realized going through your answer that the final info I had was wrong. I had to update the image, I'm sorry for the mistake.

On line 3 you made a slight mistake (don't change a string format)
There is a better interpretation of line 4 (the first comment is closer, but I'm a programmer, as a small nudge)